# Об одном из разговорных штампов

Tags: стилистика

"Как долго я тебя не видел!" А надо: "Как давно я тебя видел!". Правильно? Или этому распространённому штампу есть логическое объяснение?

Answer (score 1):

Не вижу причин называть первый из двух приведенных оборотов штампом. тем более - ставить под сомнение его абсолютную правильность. Напротив, именно второй вариант производит впечатление какой-то некорректности, неполноты... Незаконченности, что ли: "Как давно я тебя видел [последний раз]?"

Comment: Ну,конечно, я перепутал! Штамп-то другой. Обычно говорят: "Как давно я тебя не видала!". А надо: "... долго..." Сочетание "давно не видала" непонятно по смыслу... Вы на предыдущий вопрос ответили доходчиво. Спасибо.